# Get Facebook friends attending an event?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How am I able to see which of my friends attend a Facebook event? I'm able to get a list of all attendees using the Facebook SDK, withGraphPath:@"eventId/attending/".

Is what I want even possible using the Graph API? I read some answers on how to achieve this with FQL but don't know how to implement it in iOS. The only option I came up with is getting all friends and all attendees and cross-referencing them against each other, but that is very inconvenient.

So, how do I get only MY Facebook friends attending an event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I found the solution to my problem... The only way to achieve what I want is through FQL. Basically, it cross-references your friends with the attendees but on the Facebook servers, and you only receive the data you ask for (in my case user ID, name, image). I have not figured out how to set a limit and offset, but I don't require it and I think it is possible via FQL too...

Here is my code:

```
-(void)getFriendsAttending{
    NSLog(@"getting friends");
    NSString *fql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT uid, name, pic FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid FROM event_member WHERE eid = %@ AND rsvp_status = 'attending' AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()))", fbID];

    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:fql forKey:@"q"];
    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/fql"
                                 parameters:params
                                 HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                          completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                              id result,
                                              NSError *error) {
                              if (error) {
                                  NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                              } else {
                                  NSLog(@"Friends at event %@: %@", fbID, result);
                              }
                          }];

}
```

And here is the pure FQL query for clarity (123456789 - being the event ID):

```
SELECT uid, name, pic FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid FROM event_member WHERE eid = 123456789 AND rsvp_status = 'attending' AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()))
```

Comment: This just returns a blank data object :( which is weird, because the constituent parts work fine...

Comment: @nbsp its an old answer - maybe they changed it since?

Answer (score 2):

This is from the tutorial provided by Facebook

> You can check if a specific user responded 'yes' to an event by
>   issuing an HTTP GET to /EVENT_ID/attending/USER_ID. These operations
>   require the user_events or friends_events permissions for non-public
>   events and return an array of objects with the name, id, and
>   rsvp_status fields. When checking a single user, an empty data will be
>   returned if the user did not respond 'yes' to the event.

You can check it by checking the event category in this link:

> http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/

Use **/EVENT_ID/attending/USER_ID** to see which friend is attending to an event

Comment: thats clear to me, but that does mean that I will have to perform this for every single user... isn't there a way around it?

Comment: i've found that it needs to be EVENT_ID/invited/USER_ID, /attending/ does nothing (much like goggles)

Answer (score 0):

Just utilize the {event id}/attending and then filter this based on your actual friends list.

Comment: okay, but what if there are 500 attendees? I'd have to download the whole list to check it. Its more convenient to set a limit... and I do so, I will only get the friends within the limit...

Answer (score 0):

Using FQL QUery try:

```
SELECT uid FROM event_member WHERE eid = YOU_EVENT_ID_HERE AND rsvp_status = 'attending'
```

Using Graph API:

```
/YOU_EVENT_ID_HERE/attending
```

This returns the "Attending Friends" user ID's (uid).

ASH

Comment: I've already answered the question, and I'm pretty sure this would return ALL people attending, not just my friends attending.

Comment: do you have any problem with other solutions? or yours is the only possibility?