# Get facebook friends attending an event

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to use facebook graph_api to get all the friends of some user that is attending an event. I've already looked up some stuff, but it seems that the FQL query that used to work is not working anymore (please check: [Get Facebook friends attending an event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16461909/get-facebook-friends-attending-an-event)).

I've tried using /{even-id}/attending, but it returns the list of all the users that are attending the event, and it seems it's ordered by whoever confirmed the event first.

Does anyone knows how can I accomplish this?

Comment: I don't think there is a direct way to do this. I assume you need to get all the people attending, get all the friends of the person and look for the intersection. I couldn't think of a straightforward way.

Comment: Actually now that facebook cut the /friends permission, all I can do is get the friends of the person that are signed up in my app, so I just gave up on this functionality... Thanks for the reply tho.